# A question on the property of proton and neutron?

Tags: experimental-physics, subatomic

The NOVA show on the string theory have mention once that the proton and neutron will be disappear in finite amount of time, then reappearing on somewhere else. Is there any experiment have shown that this is true?

Comment: This is not true, and you are certainly misremembering. What you might be thinking about is quantum tunneling of alpha-particles out of complex nuclei, but this is not a well phrased question, because this is not "the proton and neutron" disappearing and reappearing somewhere else, but a coherent process by which a nucleus spits out an alpha particle (2 protons + 2 neutrons). Voting to close, too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume  you have heard something about [proton decay.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay)

> proton decay is a hypothetical form of radioactive decay in which the proton decays into lighter subatomic particles, such as a neutral pion and a positron.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay) There is currently no experimental evidence that proton decay occurs.

There are a number of experiments which test whether such decays occur. For example a current one is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Kamiokande).

There exist limits and in [this review](http://hep.bu.edu/~kearns/pub/kearns-pdk-snowmass.pdf) they are given depending on the theory that would predict proton decay.

Neutrons decay when free anyway into a proton an electron and an e-antineutrino.

Reappearance would require something like a new Big Bang, i.e. all matter/energy become a plasma and then by expansion the reappearance of nucleons.